# How to fix build errors in visual studio on vue.js project folder?

Tags: visual-studio, vue.js, asp.net-web-api, vuejs2, asp.net-web-api2

I used vue.js for the first time as my front end on my asp.net web api application and my vue folder is created inside my web api project. When I build the solution on my visual studio I've gotta bunch of errors relating on some files in the node_modules folder. I have no idea how to fix this errors since this is the first time I used vue.js on asp.net web api. Is there anyone have any idea to fix this issue on the build errors on visual studio? For more details on my ***package.jason*** under the script: is below. Thanks

```
"scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
```

Comment: Did you use the standard Vue.js webpack config? Does the issue only occur in VS or also when running the commands in the terminal?

Comment: @simon I don't have webpack.config on my file. Only package.jason. This only occurs when building your solution on VS. It's fine with terminal or cmd prompt.

Comment: Do I need to add webpack.config? If so, what is the sample format code?